# How to understand "lot" here?

Tags: superlatives

> Hoban: We're flying a **lot blinder** than usual here. We need to get our bearings.
> I think we need to talk to Mr. Universe.

How to understand "lot" here? Is it superlative for the word "blinder"?

Comment: ***a lot blinder*** [isn't very idiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+lot+blinder%2Ca+lot+more+blind%2Ca+lot+more+blindly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20lot%20more%20blind%3B%2Cc0) compared to ***a lot more blind*** (and hardly anyone would use explicitly adverbial [***a lot more blindly***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+lot+more+blindly%22) in your exact context). By the same token, it's usually ***We're flying blind***, rather than ***We're flying blindly***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means very much blinder than usual.

[Cambridge *a lot*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lot?q=lot_1)

> very much or very often:
> Your sister looks a lot like you.
> I'm feeling a lot better today.
> He looks a lot older than his wife.
> We used to go there a lot.

Comment: So superlative?

Comment: *blinder* is comparative, and it is intensified by *a lot*, but it's still not superlative. The superlative is *blindest*.

Comment: This is comparative: The weather is nicer today than yesterday. This is an intensified comparative: The weather is a lot nicer today than yesterday. This is a superlative: The weather is the nicest it's been for a month.